# Pandas: convert all columns in dataframe to string

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe

```
 0     1     2
12     34   23
10     12    0
```

Desire output

```
upd_string
12, 34, 23
10, 12, 0
```

I try

```
df_upd = pd.DataFrame()
df_upd['upd_string'] = df[df.columns.values.tolist()].apply(str)
```

But it returns

```
ValueError: no results
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First cast to `string`s if numeric and then apply `join`:

```
df.astype(str).apply(', '.join, axis=1)
```

for new DataFrame:

```
df_upd = pd.DataFrame({'upd_string': df.astype(str).apply(', '.join, axis=1)})
print (df_upd)
   upd_string
0  12, 34, 23
1   10, 12, 0
```

Comment: it returns `TypeError: data type not understood`

Comment: It seems some data relative problem

Comment: Are data confidental?

Comment: I create data with `df = pd.DataFrame(result_list)` where `result_list = [[12, 34, 23], [10, 12, 0]]`

Comment: I test it and for me it working perfectly. Maybe restart, upgrade pandas?

Comment: Problem has solved with restarting the kernel) Thank you!